# Issues with decals (images to planes) and surface with an AO material

Tags: transparency

[image]I am attempting to us Images to planes to put some decals on buildings I have modeled. When I do the transparent/alpha part of the PNG (or EXR makes no difference) makes the backdrop much darker. I believe this is to do with the AO material node used on the building as removing the AO part of the material resolves the issue.

The image attach demonstrates the issue. How can I fix this? Blender 2.93 cycles.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this has to do with how AO is generally handled with transparency. It should be fixed based on this very recent commit https://developer.blender.org/rBcccfa597ba6

Try rendering the scene in the latest beta release of Blender 3.0 here https://builder.blender.org/download/daily/

Comment: Thank you for this answer - I will try 3.0. However I have found a suitable workaround - if I enable  "affect local only" on the AO node then this prevents the shader from taking into account the plane when calculating the occlusion shading.